# jQuery.data() assistance

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery.data() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ to store and display values that are assigned to buttons.

The catch here is I would like to use that data in a jQuery plugin. For example a user pushes a button the values assigned to that button are sent to some more JS code which uses that data to load a youtube video.

I ran across this tutorial online which does most of what I am looking for: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/jquery-data-method/ ,but I am not sure how to load that data in my JS script and have it excite.

Any assistance or perhaps suggestions on how I made go about doing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is needing to use `.data()` in a plugin a "catch?" Also, how are we supposed to help if you haven't shown any code? You _have_ written some code ...right?

Comment: It hard to imagine what you really want.. could you build a small code  and try to explain again with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the catch is. Just use $().data on *this*:

```
$.fn.myplugin = function(options) {
    $(this).data('hi', options);

    $(this).click(function() {
        alert($(this).data('hi'));
    }); 
}

$('button').myplugin('Hello world');
```